# How nginx default_server interacts with ssl and connection refused

Tags: nginx, ssl

So I was having an issue where I had seemingly identical configurations of nginx on otherwise identical hosts, but it was working on one and not two others. Essentially trying to connect via https caused a connection refused on 2 of the servers, but the other one worked fine. This was clearly happening at the nginx level as requests weren't even making it to the process running behind nginx and fixing the nginx conf solved the problem.

nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##
        client_max_body_size 50M;
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

port 80 config in sites-enabled:

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name [my_domain].com [hostname].[subdomain].com;

    location / {
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

port 443 config in sites-enabled:

```
server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name [my_domain].com [hostname].[subdomain].com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx/[certname].pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/nginx/[certname]-key.pem;

    root /var/www/[document root]/;
    index index.html;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:[internal port];
    }

    location /web {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:[internal port];
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Initially I had `listen [::]:443 ssl;` only, which worked on host1 but not host2 and host3, adding `default_server` made host2 and host3 work properly. All three hosts were configured via saltstack with minimal interaction on my part to set them up, the only difference I've been able to think of between the hosts is that host1 and 2 are on a different provider than host3, which obviously can't be the issue. What could I have possibly missed that makes these hosts different causing the need for different configurations.

Edit: remember to check your versions, I'm an idiot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always a default server. The `default_server` option just lets you choose the default server instead of `nginx` choosing it. If your file names are different on each server, the order in which they are evaluated may be different - which means that `nginx` may have been using a different `server` block as the default on each server.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for more.

Comment: I was reading that to try to figure out what the difference between them was, the thing is that the file names on all three servers are [url] and ssl-[url] where url is the same across all three.

Comment: Hmm, that ruins an otherwise perfect answer. Have you looked at the output of `nginx -T` on each server to see if there are any strange or unexpected differences?

Comment: Well I'm an idiot, the nginx version is different, 1.2.1 on the one that worked and 1.10.3 on the ones that didn't. I assume that probably affected the order in which things were determined. I just assumed that they would be the same because it was installed via salt's state.highstate, so now the investigation will be how that happened. Thanks for the help.